# Get output from intel_gpu_top as variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, intel-graphics

Normally using grep would do the trick

```
sudo intel_gpu_top | grep xyz
```

But in this case intel_gpu_top is like htop and runs constantly.

**How would i extract the needed information inside a bash script?**

I want to get my average iGPU usage and it seems like this is the only tool that can do that. While there is an option to output the results into a file, `sudo intel_gpu_top -o file.txt` it is rather weirdly made, it has different statistics and it doesnt override the old result manually but rather adds more to the file making it difficult to read the information needed from that file (atleast for a bash noobie like me)

**EDIT:**

Here is the output from `sudo intel_gpu_top -o test.txt`

```
Freq MHz      IRQ RC6 Power     IMC MiB/s           RCS/0           BCS/0           VCS/0          VECS/0
 req  act       /s   %     W     rd     wr       %  se  wa       %  se  wa       %  se  wa       %  se  wa
   0    0        0   0  0.00    170     48    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0
   6    6       12  99  0.01    545    134    0.81   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0
   9    9       14  98  0.01    411     78    1.14   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0
   5    5       10  99  0.01    436     74    0.72   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0
  12   12       21  98  0.01    431    100    0.76   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0
   3    3        8 100  0.00    391     52    0.16   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0
```

and here from the sudo intel_gpu_top, dont forget that this will display like htop or top

```
intel-gpu-top -    9/   9 MHz;   98% RC6;  0.02 Watts;       17 irqs/s

      IMC reads:      732 MiB/s
     IMC writes:      247 MiB/s

          ENGINE      BUSY                                                                                             MI_SEMA MI_WAIT
     Render/3D/0    1.65% |█▍                                                                                        |      0%      0%
       Blitter/0    0.00% |                                                                                          |      0%      0%
         Video/0    0.00% |                                                                                          |      0%      0%
  VideoEnhance/0    0.00% |                                                                                          |      0%      0%
```

Im interrested in the Render/3D/0, Blitter/0, Video/0 and VideoEnhance/0 values. I have actually no idea how both outputs are relative to each other but yeah, if you are getting an idea please let me know.

**EDIT: EDIT:** it would be nice to get the results every "tick" i think its every second the sudo intel_gpu_top updates itself but i could be wrong

Comment: @Cbhihe I've added it, sorry that i didnt include it in the first place, totally forgot about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with that GPU version of `top`, but judging from the provided output,  it looks like `sudo intel_gpu_top` captures some of the output of `sudo intel_gpu_top -o outfile`.

The one to one correspondence seems to be:

- `Render/3D/0` <>`RCS/0` % value
- `Blitter/0` <> `BCS/0` % value
- `Video/0` <> `VCS/0` % value
- `VideoEnhance/0` <> `VECS/0` % value

Using info garnered from [GeorgeUdosen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/160267/george-udosen)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/411351/72707) on this site, borrowed from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38087477/4906636) on SO, and correctly attributed to [F.X.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821995/f-x):

- the "Render" (space) seems to be about space usage for regular 3D operations.
- the "Blitter" (engine) seems responsible for hardware acceleration of 2D operations (blitting).
- "Video Command Streamer (VCS)":

> The VCS unit primarily serves as a software programming interface
> between the OS-driver and the Multi-Format-Decoder (MFD) engine [...]
> (fetching, decoding and dispatching data packets).

see [this](https://01.org/sites/default/files/documentation/intel-gfx-prm-osrc-lkf-vol11-mediaengines.pdf) for more info

- "Video Enhance Command Streamer (VECS)": This command streamer unit is an addition/[enhancement to VCS](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTIyMzY) in that it

> allows offloading of video post processing to another new
> component, VEBOX. The VEBOX engine is used for the hardware-based
> video post processing with supported user-space code.

To get your values at regular update intervals, try:

```
$ sudo intel_gpu_top -o - \
       | awk 'BEGIN {print "\tRender/3D/0 (%)","Blitter/0 (%)","Video/0 (%)","VideoEnhance/0 (%)\n"} 
              NR>=3 {printf "\t%11s%14s%12s%%19s\n" $4,$7,$10,$13}'
```

**Edit:** I respond here to OP's author's request to limit the output to 1, i.e. to not use `intel_gpu_top` the way it's designed, that is to display its updated output at regular intervals:

To do so you can transform the above one-liner to:

```
timeout 1s sudo intel_gpu_top -s 1 -o - \
       | awk 'BEGIN {print "\tRender/3D/0 (%)","Blitter/0 (%)","Video/0 (%)","VideoEnhance/0 (%)\n"} 
              NR>=3 {printf "\t%11s%14s%12s%%19s\n" $4,$7,$10,$13}'
```

- `timeout 1s`: permits the subsequent command to time-out after one second (`1s`)
- the `intel_gpu_top` flag and parameter `-s 1` disposes that output occurs once per second.

Comment: Thanks this is pretty much what i need! But how can i make the command only output once?

Comment: Hi @Crylia: I thought you wanted the output from the command to be updated "at every "tick" as you put it . You wrote: _"EDIT: EDIT: it would be nice to get the results every "tick"_. Is not that so ?

Comment: Yes, but i meant inside a script. I might've mixed up some wordings, my bad. I've only picked up bash scripting a few days ago. This command needs to run inside a xyz.sh file that will be called by polybar every x seconds, hence the "it would be nice to get the results every "tick"". At this point i only need those four outputs saved as a variable and the rest should be easily done by myself. I'm just having a hard time using awk, sed like patterns or stringing multiple commands together. Again, my bad.

Comment: When i try to execute the command inside a script it does not timeout and is stuck. Also the option -s 1 gives me a weird result with hundrets or lines peeing printed in one second.  gpu=$(timeout 1s sudo intel_gpu_top -o - | awk 'NR>=3{printf "\t%11s%14s%12s%\n" $8,$11,$14,$17}') this is how i currently have it, it stripped away some formating stuff btw

Comment: Ok,sorry about this @Crylia, but i am really working in the dark on this one, since i cannot run test on my side.  How about: `gpu=( $(timeout 1s sudo intel_gpu_top -o - | awk 'NR>=3{print $8,$11,$14,$17}') )`. Then you can use `gpu` as you would any Bash array ...

Comment: Sadly there is still the problem that this command wont timeout, I'm not sure if its a problem with timeout or intel_gpu_top.

Comment: this is pretty weird, when typeing `timeout 1s sleep 5` it works just fine, but in combination with your command it wont exit unless executed from a terminal.
This is btw the Terminal output: `0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
[1]    682852 exit 124    timeout 1s sudo intel_gpu_top -o - | 
       682853 terminated  awk 'NR>=3{print $8,$11,$14,$17}'` maybe this helps?

Comment: Ok, so it seems like as if intel_gpu_top runs as a seperate process. I ran the command without any extras in the script and killing the script wouldnt kill the process. I had to sudo pkill intel_gpu_top after i killed the script. I think it might just not be possible :/