# intel_gpu_top output - two valiues for frequency and power consumption

Tags: monitoring, gpu, intel-graphics

In `intel_gpu_top` 1.27.1 CLI output, contrary to previous releases detailed in [Get output from intel_gpu_top as variable in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657124/get-output-from-intel-gpu-top-as-variable-in-bash) there are two values for each of frequency and power:

```
intel-gpu-top: Intel Skylake (Gen9) @ /dev/dri/card0 -  642/ 661 MHz;  38% RC6;  4.15/26.08 W;      566 irqs/s

      IMC reads:     4143 MiB/s
     IMC writes:     2146 MiB/s

         ENGINES     BUSY                                                                                                                                                                          MI_SEMA MI_WAIT
       Render/3D   46.99% |██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████                                                                                        |      0%      0%
         Blitter    0.00% |                                                                                                                                                                      |      0%      0%
           Video    0.00% |                                                                                                                                                                      |      0%      0%
    VideoEnhance    0.00% |                                                                                                                                                                      |      0%      0%

   PID              NAME                   Render/3D                                      Blitter                                        Video                                      VideoEnhance                   
1197822          kodi.bin |███████████████▏                            ||                                            ||                                            ||                                            |
     1           systemd |████▍                                       ||                                            ||                                            ||                                            |
1108342       gnome-shell |▊                                           ||                                            ||                                            ||                                            |
1108382   mutter-x11-fram |                                            ||                                            ||                                            ||                                            |
1108584         nextcloud |                                            ||                                            ||                                            ||                                            |
1108608    gnome-software |                                            ||                                            ||                                            ||                                            |
1109072   xdg-desktop-por |                                            ||                                            ||                                            ||                                            |
1109594    gnome-calendar |                                            ||                                            ||                                            ||                                            |
1110431         evolution |                                            ||                                            ||                                            ||                                            |
1110509   WebKitWebProces |                                            ||                                            ||                                            ||                                            |
1284014      gnome-clocks |                                            ||                                            ||                                            ||                                            |
1291600        input-leap |                                            ||                                            ||                                            ||                                            |
1335594            baobab |                                            ||                                            ||                                            ||                                            |
1375739          kodi.bin |                                            ||                                            ||                                            ||                                            |
```

The meaning of these two values for each of these fields was asked on [Intel-gpu-top doubts about the displayed information](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=393896).

Answer (score 0):

Outputting `intel_gpu_top` to a file via its `-o` option, instead of stdout, shows that for the power consumption the left value is for the GPU power and the right one for the package power:

```
 Freq MHz      IRQ RC6     Power W     IMC MiB/s           RCS/0           BCS/0           VCS/0          VECS/0 
 req  act       /s   %   gpu   pkg     rd     wr       %  se  wa       %  se  wa       %  se  wa       %  se  wa 
 508  508      605  24  5.14 18.79   5381   2581   56.37   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0 
 655  639      543  40  4.02 26.33   5098   2141   45.92   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0 
 664  650      549  40  4.02 25.29   4011   2056   45.76   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0 
 654  636      558  38  4.12 26.12   4126   2077   46.61   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0    0.00   0   0
```

which is confirmed by [power_items](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/intel-gpu-tools/tree/tools/intel_gpu_top.c?id=f366406b05ca6b3d16eaa734a91e0833bd159f54#n1513) and [print_header_token](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/intel-gpu-tools/tree/tools/intel_gpu_top.c?id=f366406b05ca6b3d16eaa734a91e0833bd159f54#n1609)

For the frequency values, from [init_aggregate_counters](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/intel-gpu-tools/tree/tools/intel_gpu_top.c?id=f366406b05ca6b3d16eaa734a91e0833bd159f54#n564), [freq_items](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/intel-gpu-tools/tree/tools/intel_gpu_top.c?id=f366406b05ca6b3d16eaa734a91e0833bd159f54#n1438) and [print_header_token](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/intel-gpu-tools/tree/tools/intel_gpu_top.c?id=f366406b05ca6b3d16eaa734a91e0833bd159f54#n1583) the left frequency value is the actual one ("act") while the right one is the requested one ("req").